How to change <rights> tag to <copyright> in Atom feed?
I am using the feed module to generate an Atom feed in CAP format. Here is the code I am using to generate the feed:
const feed = new Feed({
    title: 'Event Notifications',
    generator: 'Custom CAP XML Generator',
    description: 'Notifications for events',
    id: config.url + '/notifications.atom',
    link: config.url + '/notifications.atom',
    updated: new Date(),
    author: {
      name: 'Notification Agency',
      email: 'contact@notification-agency.example.com',
      link: 'https://www.notification-agency.example.com'
    },
    copyright: 'https://www.example.com/open-license'
});

I have been asked to change the <rights> tag to <copyright> in the generated feed. However, the module automatically generates a <rights> tag, and all the documentation I found indicates that it should be <rights>. I am not sure enough about the CAP format or Atom feeds to confirm if this is correct or if I should push back on this request.
If it is indeed correct that the <rights> tag should be <copyright>, I came up with a workaround to "shoehorn" the <copyright> tag into the feed as follows:
const atomFeed = feed.atom1();

const copyrightText = '\n<copyright>Copyright (c) 2024, Notification Agency. Licensed under Creative Commons BY 4.0</copyright>';

const subtitleTag = '</subtitle>';
const subtitlePosition = atomFeed.indexOf(subtitleTag) + subtitleTag.length;
const feedWithCopyright = `${atomFeed.slice(0, subtitlePosition)}${copyrightText}${atomFeed.slice(subtitlePosition)}`;

My questions are:

Is it correct to use the <copyright> tag in an Atom feed for CAP format, or should it be <rights>?

If <copyright> is indeed the correct tag, is my workaround an acceptable solution, or is there a better way to handle this within the feed module?



You are reading XML data.  If copyright is needed it should be put into code that saves xml on the website.  It is a kludge to edit the xml when downloading.

There is no atom:copyright element, only atom:rights. the <copyright> element is an RSS element.

After more research and pushing back on the ask I've had it confirmed copyright is used in RSS, rights for ATOM. So I can keep it as Atom which makes a lot more sense
